# clicking on an image from a gallery and showing multiple images in the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have an image gallery and I want to click on each image to show 4 related image to it. What is the best way to do this without creating a whole new page for each image to show its related images?

I am using this for image gallery:
http://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/ZYbPJM

For now I have used Adobe InDesign to show the four images in one png file (due to space limits) but of course there are more aesthetic and smart ways. Please suggest solutions.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Imgur Results</title>


  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/photoswipe/4.1.1/photoswipe.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/photoswipe/4.1.1/default-skin/default-skin.min.css'>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">



</head>

<body>
  <h2>Banana:</h2>

  <div class="my-gallery" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">

    <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
      <a href="imgur/banana/banana1.png" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="900x900">

          <img  src="imgur/banana/3NlNsLB.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description"  />

      </a>

    </figure>



    <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
      <a href="imgur/banana/banana2.tif" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="900x900">
          <img src="imgur/banana/6gqpgDV.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" />
      </a>
    </figure>
```

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/photoswipe/4.1.1/photoswipe.min.js'>

```
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

Here's the js:

```
var initPhotoSwipeFromDOM = function(gallerySelector) {

    // parse slide data (url, title, size ...) from DOM elements 
    // (children of gallerySelector)
    var parseThumbnailElements = function(el) {
        var thumbElements = el.childNodes,
            numNodes = thumbElements.length,
            items = [],
            figureEl,
            linkEl,
            size,
            item;

        for(var i = 0; i < numNodes; i++) {

            figureEl = thumbElements[i]; // <figure> element

            // include only element nodes 
            if(figureEl.nodeType !== 1) {
                continue;
            }

            linkEl = figureEl.children[0]; // <a> element

            size = linkEl.getAttribute('data-size').split('x');

            // create slide object
            item = {
                src: linkEl.getAttribute('href'),
                w: parseInt(size[0], 10),
                h: parseInt(size[1], 10)
            };



            if(figureEl.children.length > 1) {
                // <figcaption> content
                item.title = figureEl.children[1].innerHTML; 
            }

            if(linkEl.children.length > 0) {
                // <img> thumbnail element, retrieving thumbnail url
                item.msrc = linkEl.children[0].getAttribute('src');
            } 

            item.el = figureEl; // save link to element for getThumbBoundsFn
            items.push(item);
        }

        return items;
    };

    // find nearest parent element
    var closest = function closest(el, fn) {
        return el && ( fn(el) ? el : closest(el.parentNode, fn) );
    };

    // triggers when user clicks on thumbnail
    var onThumbnailsClick = function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;

        var eTarget = e.target || e.srcElement;

        // find root element of slide
        var clickedListItem = closest(eTarget, function(el) {
            return (el.tagName && el.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'FIGURE');
        });

        if(!clickedListItem) {
            return;
        }

        // find index of clicked item by looping through all child nodes
        // alternatively, you may define index via data- attribute
        var clickedGallery = clickedListItem.parentNode,
            childNodes = clickedListItem.parentNode.childNodes,
            numChildNodes = childNodes.length,
            nodeIndex = 0,
            index;

        for (var i = 0; i < numChildNodes; i++) {
            if(childNodes[i].nodeType !== 1) { 
                continue; 
            }

            if(childNodes[i] === clickedListItem) {
                index = nodeIndex;
                break;
            }
            nodeIndex++;
        }



        if(index >= 0) {
            // open PhotoSwipe if valid index found
            openPhotoSwipe( index, clickedGallery );
        }
        return false;
    };

    // parse picture index and gallery index from URL (#&pid=1&gid=2)
    var photoswipeParseHash = function() {
        var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1),
        params = {};

        if(hash.length < 5) {
            return params;
        }

        var vars = hash.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
            if(!vars[i]) {
                continue;
            }
            var pair = vars[i].split('=');  
            if(pair.length < 2) {
                continue;
            }           
            params[pair[0]] = pair[1];
        }

        if(params.gid) {
            params.gid = parseInt(params.gid, 10);
        }

        return params;
    };

    var openPhotoSwipe = function(index, galleryElement, disableAnimation, fromURL) {
        var pswpElement = document.querySelectorAll('.pswp')[0],
            gallery,
            options,
            items;

        items = parseThumbnailElements(galleryElement);

        // define options (if needed)
        options = {

            // define gallery index (for URL)
            galleryUID: galleryElement.getAttribute('data-pswp-uid'),

            getThumbBoundsFn: function(index) {
                // See Options -> getThumbBoundsFn section of documentation for more info
                var thumbnail = items[index].el.getElementsByTagName('img')[0], // find thumbnail
                    pageYScroll = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
                    rect = thumbnail.getBoundingClientRect(); 

                return {x:rect.left, y:rect.top + pageYScroll, w:rect.width};
            }

        };

        // PhotoSwipe opened from URL
        if(fromURL) {
            if(options.galleryPIDs) {
                // parse real index when custom PIDs are used 
                // http://photoswipe.com/documentation/faq.html#custom-pid-in-url
                for(var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
                    if(items[j].pid == index) {
                        options.index = j;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // in URL indexes start from 1
                options.index = parseInt(index, 10) - 1;
            }
        } else {
            options.index = parseInt(index, 10);
        }

        // exit if index not found
        if( isNaN(options.index) ) {
            return;
        }

        if(disableAnimation) {
            options.showAnimationDuration = 0;
        }

        // Pass data to PhotoSwipe and initialize it
        gallery = new PhotoSwipe( pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);
        gallery.init();
    };

    // loop through all gallery elements and bind events
    var galleryElements = document.querySelectorAll( gallerySelector );

    for(var i = 0, l = galleryElements.length; i < l; i++) {
        galleryElements[i].setAttribute('data-pswp-uid', i+1);
        galleryElements[i].onclick = onThumbnailsClick;
    }

    // Parse URL and open gallery if it contains #&pid=3&gid=1
    var hashData = photoswipeParseHash();
    if(hashData.pid && hashData.gid) {
        openPhotoSwipe( hashData.pid ,  galleryElements[ hashData.gid - 1 ], true, true );
    }
};

// execute above function
initPhotoSwipeFromDOM('.my-gallery');
```

here's the CSS:

```
.my-gallery {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.my-gallery img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
}
.my-gallery figure {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 15px 20px 0;
  border: 3px solid #000;

}

.my-gallery figcaption {
  display: none;
}
```

Also is there an easier way to have this image gallery without using this library above?

Basically I would like to show something like this when you click on an image:
[image]
^ the above is made with adobe illustrator though and would be nice to make it with html/css.

This is how the gallery itself shows:
[image]

Comment: Hey what if you used something like this CSS Modal and just populated it with your 4 images? http://codepen.io/ohnoitsaustin/pen/zGmJjz

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using Fancybox.

[See this Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/q8bn6/63/)

In this example, clicking on the visible image triggers a click event that opens an hidden gallery using Fancybox.

HTML

```
<!-- Your visible image(s) -->
    <a class="fancyboxLauncher" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg" title="one"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>

<!-- Your hidden gallery -->    
    <div style="display: none;">
    <a class="fancybox" href="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3712/9032543579_1217e6566b_b.jpg" title="one"></a>

<a class="fancybox" href="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3818/9036037912_83576fe5ab_b.jpg" title="two"></a>
```

JS

```
// Trigger event
$(".fancyboxLauncher").on("click", function () {
    $(".fancybox").eq(0).trigger("click");
    return false;
});

// Init Fancybox
$(".fancybox")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
    padding: 0
});
```

You can still use the 4-in-1 image of course, just use 1 image instead of 4. Regardless, you have a lot of options with it.